# Sharpe ratio: discrete or continuous returns?

Tags: returns, sharpe-ratio, performance-evaluation, performance, sharpe

The Sharpe ratio is known as
$$SR=\frac{\mu-r_f}{\sigma}$$
Are these values calculated from discrete or continuously compounded returns?

Comment: possibly related: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1102/should-sharpe-ratio-be-computed-using-log-returns-or-relative-returns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For client reporting purposes, it is customary to use discrete returns. For backtesting, it pretty much make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

These are the *realized* return and standard deviation for the portfolio over the period.

Source: Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance, sec. ed., p. 329-330